# Inserting Inputs in Dynamically imported Components in Angular

Tags: angular, input, components

I have a function that i am using to import components from an angular core application to all libraries.
This function returns the component as a dom element and i am appending it in the child libraries.
now i want to get the component but while giving it some inputs.

this is the code i am using. i am not getting any error but the input property is not being seen.

**Function that returns the component as dom element**

```
getComponent(componentInput?: string): HTMLElement {

const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SharedcomponentComponent); 
const componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);

//Injecting Inputs to the component instance
if(componentInput != undefined){
   componentRef.instance.someProp = componentInput;
}

this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
return domElem;
}
```

**My Component**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-sharedcomponent',
templateUrl: './sharedcomponent.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sharedcomponent.component.css']
})


export class SharedcomponentComponent implements OnInit {

@Input('someProp') someProp: string;
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {

}

clickMe(){
  alert("I am the core component :)");
}
```

}

**My Component Html**

```
<button (click)="clickMe()">
  Click Me :)
</button>
<br/>
<p>
  Hello there {{someProp}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
The below code is working fine now

```
getComponent(componentInput?: string): HTMLElement {

const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SharedcomponentComponent); 
const componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);

//Injecting Inputs to the component instance
if(componentInput != undefined){
  let inputs = { someProp: componentInput };

  Object.keys(inputs).map(input => {
    componentRef.instance[input] = inputs[input];
  });
}

this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<SharedcomponentComponent>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
return domElem;
```

}